# onLoadFinished is not called properly from ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I have two different SimpleCursorAdapters and linked ListViews in MainActivity. Initializing them with:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(2, null, this);
```

After initialization, both loaders are created and ran queries on ContentProvider with correctly returned data.

LoaderManager implementations:

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader loader = null;

        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                loader = new CursorLoader(this,
                        DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE_Match,
                        new String[]{DataProvider.COL_ID, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, DataProvider.COL_COUNT, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE},
                        null,
                        null,
                        DataProvider.COL_ID + " DESC");
                break;
            case 2:
                loader = new CursorLoader(this,
                        DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE_Trash,
                        new String[]{DataProvider.COL_ID, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, DataProvider.COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE},
                        null,
                        null,
                        DataProvider.COL_ID + " DESC");
                break;
        }
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case 0:
                adapterMatch.swapCursor(data);
                break;
            case 2:
                adapterTrash.swapCursor(data);
                break;
        }
    }
```

The app works as follow. when receiving a message from server on BroadCastReceiver, below part of code will run on Receiver class and insert a row in db via ContentProvider

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(5);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_MATCH_ID, matchedUser);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS, expirationStatus);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, matchName);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE, matchBirthDate);
                    values.put(DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, matchProfileImage);
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_PROFILE_Match, values);
```

My problem is after inserting new values received from server to SQLite database, cursor data is not passed to MainActivity, so not updating the UI until next time Activity is created.

Below is the highlighted codes from my ContentProvider :

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES = Uri.parse("content://com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider/messages");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PROFILE = Uri.parse("content://com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider/profile");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PROFILE_Match = Uri.parse("content://com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider/match");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PROFILE_Trash = Uri.parse("content://com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider/trash");

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "messages", MESSAGES_ALLROWS);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "messages/#", MESSAGES_SINGLE_ROW);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "profile", PROFILE_ALLROWS);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "profile/#", PROFILE_SINGLE_ROW);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "match", PROFILE_AllROWS_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "match/#", PROFILE_SINGLE_ROWS_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI("com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider", "trash", PROFILE_ALLROWS_TRASH);
    }

@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MESSAGES_ALLROWS:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_MESSAGES);
            break;          

        case MESSAGES_SINGLE_ROW:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_MESSAGES);
            qb.appendWhere("_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;

        case PROFILE_ALLROWS:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_PROFILE);
            break;          

        case PROFILE_SINGLE_ROW:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_PROFILE);
            qb.appendWhere("_id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;

        case PROFILE_AllROWS_MATCH:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_PROFILE);
            qb.appendWhere(COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS + " = " + "'wait'" + " OR " + COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS + " = " + "'active'");
            break;

        case PROFILE_ALLROWS_TRASH:
            qb.setTables(TABLE_PROFILE);
            qb.appendWhere(COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS + " = " + "'expired'");
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);          
        }

        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }

@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        long id;
        switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MESSAGES_ALLROWS:
            id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_MESSAGES, null, values);
            if (values.get(COL_TO) == null) {
                db.execSQL("update profile set count = count+1 where email = ?", new Object[]{values.get(COL_FROM)});
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_PROFILE, null);
            }
            break;

        case PROFILE_ALLROWS:
            id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);
            break;

        case PROFILE_AllROWS_MATCH:
            id = db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_PROFILE, null, values);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
        }

        Uri insertUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertUri, null);

        return insertUri;
    }
```

I've searched many SO questions and android resources, but cannot find any clue to solve this problem. Any solutions please?

**Edit:** below added the codes for setting up SimpleCursorAdapters:

```
adapterMatch = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.main_list_item,
                null,
                new String[]{DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE, DataProvider.COL_COUNT, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_ID},
                new int[]{R.id.avatar, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3},
                0);
adapterWatch = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.main_list_item,
                    null,
                    new String[]{DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE, DataProvider.COL_MUTUAL_ACTION, DataProvider.COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_ID},
                    new int[]{R.id.avatar, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3},
                    0);
adapterTrash = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.main_list_item,
                    null,
                    new String[]{DataProvider.COL_MATCH_PROFILE_IMAGE, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_NAME, DataProvider.COL_MATCH_BIRTH_DATE, DataProvider.COL_EXPIRATION_STATUS},
                    new int[]{R.id.avatar, R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3},
                    0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be nothing, but would you mind debugging and checking the value of the `insertUri` variable on the 4th last line of the `insert` method in your `ContentProvider` when a match is inserted?

Comment: inertUri variable is "content://com.example.vcc4.mashroom.provider/match" after inserting a match

Comment: Thanks! Okay, it doesn't look like what I thought it might be.

Comment: Would you mind posting the code where you create the `SimpleCursorAdapter`s you are using to handle the loaded data?

Comment: Thank you @clownba0t. I've added requested lines of code to edit section.

Comment: Looks to me like everything is set up correctly - the cursors involved have the appropriate notification URI set, a notification is sent by the ContentProvider when you insert to that URI, and your adapters are correctly set up with flag `0` so that they don't do their own cursor change handling. I'm terribly sorry but I can't think of anything else - hopefully someone else can!

Comment: yep, it seems OK to me too and this is more confusing. By the way, thank you for trying..